# Flash file as OSX screensaver using xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, flash, screensaver

I'm trying to create a screensaver from an SWF file for mac.
Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get started. I've looked on the internet for hints on how to do this but with no success.

Does anyone know how I can get an SWF file as screensaver with xcode, or possibly another option?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried looking on the internet for a method to do this and I've tried to make something with the information I could find. Unfortunately the only results I've got are errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get started by:

1) Get a basic screen saver working from the sample code or tutorial like this:
http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000088.php

2) Get your SWF file going in a basic Mac app ( Maybe use a web view?).

3) Merge the two together.